# PHP split string at last number, insert an extra string and merge the new string

Tags: php, string, math, time, split

I have build a calculating script that takes seconds and show them in y:d:h:m:s containing labels etc.

eg. `15768012` = `1 year 12 seconds` and `27362` = `15 hours 6 minutes 2 seconds`.

The script works perfectly, but I would like to look in the string and split it by the last number (not the first) and then insert the word `and` so that:

`15768012` = `1 year AND 12 seconds` and `27362` = `15 hours 6 minutes AND 2 seconds`.

I can write my script if you need it, but I don't think it will help you solve this question..

let's say that `$string = '15 hours 6 minutes 2 seconds'` how would you split it and import the text `and` ?

```
<?
if (isset($_POST['number'])) {
    $x = $_POST['number'];
} else {
    $x = 54098;
}

// Labels
$lb_y = 'year';
$lb_ys = 'years';
$lb_d = 'day';
$lb_ds = 'days';
$lb_h = 'hour';
$lb_hs = 'hours';
$lb_m = 'minute';
$lb_ms = 'minutes';
$lb_s = 'second';
$lb_ss = 'seconds';
$lb_and = 'and';

//$x = 54098; // Time in seconds - change to $row['time'];

$f = 15768000; // seconds in a year
$d = 43200; // seconds in a day
$t = 3600; // seconds in an hour
$m = 60; // senconds in a minute


// Let's check if it is more than a minute
if ($x >= $m) {

    // More than a minute
    // Let's check if it is more than an hour
    if ($x >= $t) {

        // More than an hour
        // Let's check if it is more than a day
        if($x >= $d) {

            // More than a day
            // Let's check if it is more than a year
            if ($x >= $f) {

                // More than a year
                // Calculate years
                $a = $x / $f;

                // Get everything before the separator '.'
                if (false !== ($cal = strpos($a, '.'))) {
                    $a = substr($a, 0, $cal);
                }

                // $k = what's left
                $k = $x - ($f * $a);

                // Calculate days
                $b = $k / $d;

                // Get everything before the separator '.'
                if (false !== ($cal = strpos($b, '.'))) {
                    $b = substr($b, 0, $cal);
                }

                // $y = what's left
                $y = $k - ($d * $b);

                // Calculate hours
                $c = $y / $t;

                // Get everything before the separator '.'
                if (false !== ($cal = strpos($c, '.'))) {
                    $c = substr($c, 0, $cal);
                }

                // $z = what's left
                $z = $y - ($t * $c);

                // Calculate minutes
                $e = $z / $m;

                // Get everything before the separator '.'
                if (false !== ($cal = strpos($e, '.'))) {
                    $e = substr($e, 0, $cal);
                }

                // $q = what's left
                $q = $z - ($m * $e);

                // Rewrite numbers if below 9
                if ($a <= 9) { $xa = '0'.$a; } else { $xa = $a; }
                if ($b <= 9) { $xb = '0'.$b; } else { $xb = $b; }
                if ($c <= 9) { $xc = '0'.$c; } else { $xc = $c; }
                if ($e <= 9) { $xe = '0'.$e; } else { $xe = $e; }
                if ($q <= 9) { $xq = '0'.$q; } else { $xq = $q; }

                // Rewrite labels
                if ($a <= 1) { $lb_ys = $lb_y; }
                if ($b <= 1) { $lb_ds = $lb_d; }
                if ($c <= 1) { $lb_hs = $lb_h; }
                if ($e <= 1) { $lb_ms = $lb_m; }
                if ($q <= 1) { $lb_ss = $lb_s; }

                // if == 0 - do not show
                $a = $a.' '.$lb_ys.' ';
                if ($b == 0) {$b = '';} else {$b = $b.' '.$lb_ds.' ';}
                if ($c == 0) {$c = '';} else {$c = $c.' '.$lb_hs.' ';}
                if ($e == 0) {$e = '';} else {$e = $e.' '.$lb_ms.' ';}
                if ($q == 0) {$q = '';} else {$q = $q.' '.$lb_ss;}

                echo $xa.':'.$xb.':'.$xc.':'.$xe.':'.$xq;
                echo '<br>'.$a.$b.$c.$e.$q;


            } else {

                // Less than a year - but more than one day
                // Calculate days
                $b = $x / $d;

                // Get everything before the separator '.'
                if (false !== ($cal = strpos($b, '.'))) {
                    $b = substr($b, 0, $cal);
                }

                // $y = what's left
                $y = $x - ($d * $b);

                // Calculate hours
                $c = $y / $t;

                // Get everything before the separator '.'
                if (false !== ($cal = strpos($c, '.'))) {
                    $c = substr($c, 0, $cal);
                }

                // $z = what's left
                $z = $y - ($t * $c);

                // Calculate minutes
                $e = $z / $m;

                // Get everything before the separator '.'
                if (false !== ($cal = strpos($e, '.'))) {
                    $e = substr($e, 0, $cal);
                }

                // $q = what's left
                $q = $z - ($m * $e);

                // Rewrite numbers if below 9
                if ($b <= 9) { $xb = '0'.$b; } else { $xb = $b; }
                if ($c <= 9) { $xc = '0'.$c; } else { $xc = $c; }
                if ($e <= 9) { $xe = '0'.$e; } else { $xe = $e; }
                if ($q <= 9) { $xq = '0'.$q; } else { $xq = $q; }

                // Rewrite labels
                if ($b <= 1) { $lb_ds = $lb_d; }
                if ($c <= 1) { $lb_hs = $lb_h; }
                if ($e <= 1) { $lb_ms = $lb_m; }
                if ($q <= 1) { $lb_ss = $lb_s; }

                // if == 0 - do not show
                $b = $b.' '.$lb_ds.' ';
                if ($c == 0) {$c = '';} else {$c = $c.' '.$lb_hs.' ';}
                if ($e == 0) {$e = '';} else {$e = $e.' '.$lb_ms.' ';}
                if ($q == 0) {$q = '';} else {$q = $q.' '.$lb_ss;}

                echo $xb.':'.$xc.':'.$xe.':'.$xq;
                echo '<br>'.$b.$c.$e.$q;
            }

        } else {

            // Less than a day
            // Calculate hours
            $c = $x / $t;

            // Get everything before the separator '.'
            if (false !== ($cal = strpos($c, '.'))) {
                $c = substr($c, 0, $cal);
            }

            // $z = what's left
            $z = $x - ($t * $c);

            // Calculate minutes
            $e = $z / $m;

            // Get everything before the separator '.'
            if (false !== ($cal = strpos($e, '.'))) {
                $e = substr($e, 0, $cal);
            }

            // $q = what's left
            $q = $z - ($m * $e);

            // Rewrite numbers if below 9
            if ($c <= 9) { $xc = '0'.$c; } else { $xc = $c; }
            if ($e <= 9) { $xe = '0'.$e; } else { $xe = $e; }
            if ($q <= 9) { $xq = '0'.$q; } else { $xq = $q; }

            // Rewrite labels
            if ($c <= 1) { $lb_hs = $lb_h; }
            if ($e <= 1) { $lb_ms = $lb_m; }
            if ($q <= 1) { $lb_ss = $lb_s; }

            // if == 0 - do not show
            $c = $c.' '.$lb_hs.' ';
            if ($e == 0) {$e = '';} else {$e = $e.' '.$lb_ms.' ';}
            if ($q == 0) {$q = '';} else {$q = $q.' '.$lb_ss;}

            echo $xc.':'.$xe.':'.$xq;
            echo '<br>'.$c.$e.$q;

        }

    } else {

        // Less than an hour
        // Calculate minutes
        $e = $x / $m;

        // Get everything before the separator '.'
        if (false !== ($cal = strpos($e, '.'))) {
            $e = substr($e, 0, $cal);
        }

        // $q = what's left
        $q = $x - ($m * $e);

        // Rewrite numbers if below 9
        if ($e <= 9) { $xe = '0'.$e; } else { $xe = $e; }
        if ($q <= 9) { $xq = '0'.$q; } else { $xq = $q; }

        // Rewrite labels
        if ($e <= 1) { $lb_ms = $lb_m; }
        if ($q <= 1) { $lb_ss = $lb_s; }

        // if == 0 - do not show
        $e = $e.' '.$lb_ms.' ';
        if ($q == 0) {$q = '';} else {$q = $q.' '.$lb_ss;}

        echo $xe.':'.$xq;
        echo '<br>'.$e.$q;

    }

} else {

    // Less than a minute
    // Only secounds

    // Rewrite numbers if below 9
    if ($x <= 9) { $xx = '0'.$x; } else { $xx = $x; }

    // Rewrite labels
    if ($x <= 1) { $lb_ss = $lb_s; }

    // if == 0 - do not show
    $x = $x.' '.$lb_ss;

    echo '00:'.$xx;
    echo '<br>'.$x;

}
?>

<form action="" method="post"><input name="number" type="text"><input name="" type="submit" value="Submit"></form>
```

Thanks everybody for your help.. here is the simplified and done script.. I have a new problem though.. when you type less than `1576` in the field, it writes some different numbers than I want it to...

EDIT: Problem now fixed.. Welcome to use the script :D

```
<?
if (isset($_POST['number'])) {
    $x = $_POST['number'];
} else {
    $x = 54098;
}

// Labels
$lb_y = 'year';
$lb_ys = 'years';
$lb_d = 'day';
$lb_ds = 'days';
$lb_h = 'hour';
$lb_hs = 'hours';
$lb_m = 'minute';
$lb_ms = 'minutes';
$lb_s = 'second';
$lb_ss = 'seconds';
$lb_and = 'and';

//$x = 54098; // Time in seconds - change to $row['time'];

$f = 15768000; // seconds in a year
$d = 43200; // seconds in a day
$h = 3600; // seconds in an hour
$m = 60; // seconds in a minute

$a = $x / $f;
if (false !== ($cal = strpos($a, 'E-'))) { $a = 0; }
if (false !== ($cal = strpos($a, '.'))) { $a = substr($a, 0, $cal); }
if ($a <= 0) { $a = 0; }
$b = ($x - ($f * $a)) / $d;
if (false !== ($cal = strpos($b, 'E-'))) { $b = 0; }
if (false !== ($cal = strpos($b, '.'))) { $b = substr($b, 0, $cal); }
if ($b <= 0) { $b = 0; }
$c = ($x - ($f * $a) - ($d * $b)) / $h;
if (false !== ($cal = strpos($c, 'E-'))) { $c = 0; }
if (false !== ($cal = strpos($c, '.'))) { $c = substr($c, 0, $cal); }
if ($c <= 0) { $c = 0; }
$e = ($x - ($f * $a) - ($d * $b) - ($h * $c)) / $m;
if (false !== ($cal = strpos($e, '.'))) { $e = substr($e, 0, $cal); }
if ($e <= 0) { $e = 0; }
$q = ($x - ($f * $a) - ($d * $b) - ($h * $c) - ($m * $e));

// Rewrite numbers if below 9
if ($a <= 9) { $xa = '0'.$a; } else { $xa = $a; }
if ($b <= 9) { $xb = '0'.$b; } else { $xb = $b; }
if ($c <= 9) { $xc = '0'.$c; } else { $xc = $c; }
if ($e <= 9) { $xe = '0'.$e; } else { $xe = $e; }
if ($q <= 9) { $xq = '0'.$q; } else { $xq = $q; }

// Rewrite labels
if ($a <= 1) { $lb_ys = $lb_y; }
if ($b <= 1) { $lb_ds = $lb_d; }
if ($c <= 1) { $lb_hs = $lb_h; }
if ($e <= 1) { $lb_ms = $lb_m; }
if ($q <= 1) { $lb_ss = $lb_s; }

// if == 0 - do not show
if ($a == 0) {$a = '';} else {$a = $a.' '.$lb_ys;}
if ($b == 0) {$b = '';} else {$b = $b.' '.$lb_ds;}
if ($c == 0) {$c = '';} else {$c = $c.' '.$lb_hs;}
if ($e == 0) {$e = '';} else {$e = $e.' '.$lb_ms;}
if ($q == 0) {$q = '';} else {$q = $q.' '.$lb_ss;}

echo $xa.':'.$xb.':'.$xc.':'.$xe.':'.$xq.'<br>';

$time = array($a, $b, $c, $e, $q);

$time = array_filter($time);
$count = count($time);
$last = array_pop($time);
if ($count == 1) {
    $string = $last;
} elseif ($count == 0) {
    $string = '<i>No Time described</i>';
} else {
    $string = implode(', ', $time) . ' '.$lb_and.' ' . $last;
}

echo '<br>'.$string;

?>
<br><br>
<form action="" method="post"><input name="number" type="text"><input name="" type="submit" value="Submit"></form>
```

Comment: 'I can write my script if you need it, but I don't think it will help you solve this question'. Yes we do need, and yes it will help us

Comment: You may also want to consider adding a comma (i.e. ,) between 'hours' and '6' in your last example, which some people would say is most correct when writing things as a list

Comment: That's easy enough afterwords.. but good idea.. :)

Comment: `$t = 1800; // seconds in a hours` really?

Comment: The comment typo wasn't the main problem; there are 3600 seconds in an hour.

Comment: oh yeah.. didn't notice that..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick fix may be:

```
$string = '15 hours 6 minutes 2 seconds';
$pattern ='/ \d+ \w+$/';
$string = preg_replace($pattern, ' and$0', $string);
```

However, you may want to look into a nicer solution which resulted in the following array being built:

```
$time = array($a, $b, $c, $e, $q);
```

You could then do:

```
$time = array_filter($time);
$last = array_pop($time);
$string = implode(', ', $time) . ' and ' . $last;
```

Comment: I like this one... I could imagine that a way to use it would be lie this: `$time = array($a, $b, $c, $e, $q);
     
     $last = array_pop($time);
     $string = implode(', ', $time) . ' and ' . $last;
     
     echo $string;` If you look at the first big calculation. But then the result is like this: `1 year , , , and 12 seconds`.

Comment: @Philip - Remove the empty array elements with [`array_filter()`](http://www.php.net/array_filter).

Answer (score 2):

That looks rather long and tedious, when you could use the division to help figure out the values as you go.  That way, you can then do logic on them one at a time (to figure out if they need (s) on the end or not.

```
$x / $f = $years
($x - ($f * $years)) / $d = $days
($x - ($f * $years) - ($d * $days)) / $h = $hours
($x - ($f * $years) - ($d * $days) - ($h * $hours)) / $m = $minutes
($x - ($f * $years) - ($d * $days) - ($h * $hours) - ($m * $minutes)) = $seconds
```

Basically as it goes, it figures out how much is left of the remainder of each of the previous calculations.  Simple example is if your number is 1 second bigger then 2 years.

Years would give 2, with 1 remainder.  You subtract away the portion you already accounted for and keep dividing up into smaller sections as you go.  This way, you can handle each individual number easier for formatting purposes.

Comment: I have reprogrammed the script to work with your great idea.. but there is a problem though.. check the edit..

Comment: From the looks of it, you have the $q (for seconds) messed up.  I see you are dividing by $s (I am assuming a constant for seconds matching the structure you used before).  Once you have calculated years, days, hours, etc. all that is left is seconds.  There is no need for division again.  Just take the totals from everything and subtract.  I also don't think you have $s initialized, which is not really needed.  Try this for $q...
`$q = ($x - ($f * $a) - ($d * $b) - ($h * $c) - ($m * $e))`

Comment: I found the error.. It seems like that if I type a number below `1576` the `$a` will be equal to a number containing `e` like `7.1876254E1`.. Thereby, the script saw `$a` as `7.18` and then it assumed that it was 7 years.. The error is fixed by writing: `if (!is_int($a)) {$a = 0;}` after the `$a` - calculation.

Answer (score 0):

As what you've already achieved is relatively complex, I assume you only need some hints; so:

- `explode` function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php
- as you know your string ends with a number and its units, ignore the last 2 elements of the array produced by `explode`
- loop (in whatever way you see fit, not necessarily a traditional `for` loop) through the array and add 'and' in.

Comment: I agree with Paolo that incorporating it into your main function would be best; I was assuming that 'seconds' might not always be present (do you have '10 minutes and 0 seconds' or just '10 minutes' when you start with 6000?)

Answer (score 0):

It would be more efficient if you build it directly in your function , but in the meantime you can use preg_replace.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

```
$string = '15 hours 6 minutes 2 seconds'

$pattern ='/(\d+)\sseconds/';

$string =preg_replace($pattern,' And $1 seconds',$string);
```

Comment: What about the string `6 hours 2 minutes`?

Comment: Yeah.. that's also what I started out by making, but then the problem will appear, if there is no seconds at all.. `10 days 4 minutes`