# Javascript calculation function doesn't work

Tags: javascript, function, jsfiddle

Here is a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m54Du/).
The script speaks for itself. I just want to point out that it doesn't work. Please take a look and tell me what to do different. Thanks in advance. I have followed what I believe is every rule in javascript programming, but somewhere somehow I must have overlooked something. I have also made an actual working version og the script i PHP. The working PHP is the second script in this post: [PHP split string at last number, insert an extra string and merge the new string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14463110/php-split-string-at-last-number-insert-an-extra-string-and-merge-the-new-string).

```
function calTime(x) {

if (x === '') {
    x = 54098;
} // Time in seconds
var f = 31536000, // seconds in a year
    d = 86400, // seconds in a day
    h = 3600, // seconds in an hour
    m = 60, // seconds in a minute
    xa,
    xb,
    xc,
    xe,
    xq,
    string,
    lb_y = 'year',
    lb_ys = 'years',
    lb_d = 'day',
    lb_ds = 'days',
    lb_h = 'hour',
    lb_hs = 'hours',
    lb_m = 'minute',
    lb_ms = 'minutes',
    lb_s = 'second',
    lb_ss = 'seconds',
    lb_and = 'and';

// a = years
var a = x / f;

// To prevent complications using scientific numbers less than 0 ex 7.2341232E-23
var a1 = a.indexOf("E-");
if (a1) {
    a = 0;
}

// Split a so we only get the numbers before '.'
var a2 = a.indexOf(".");
if (a2) {
    Math.floor(a);
}

// if $a is less or equal to 0 - it is 0
if (a <= 0) {
    a = 0;
}

// b = days
var b = (x - (f * a)) / d;

// To prevent complications using scientific numbers less than 0 ex 7.2341232E-23
var b1 = b.indexOf("E-");
if (b1) {
    b = 0;
}

// Split b so we only get the numbers before '.'
var b2 = b.indexOf(".");
if (b2) {
    Math.floor(b);
}

// if $b is less or equal to 0 - it is 0
if (b <= 0) {
    b = 0;
}

// c = hours
var c = (x - (f * a) - (d * b)) / h;

// To prevent complications using scientific numbers less than 0 ex 7.2341232E-23
var c1 = c.indexOf("E-");
if (c1) {
    c = 0;
}

// Split c so we only get the numbers before '.'
var c2 = c.indexOf(".");
if (c2) {
    Math.floor(c);
}

// if $c is less or equal to 0 - it is 0
if (c <= 0) {
    c = 0;
}

// e = minutes
var e = (x - (f * a) - (d * b) - (h * c)) / m;

// Split $e so we only get the numbers before '.'
var e2 = e.indexOf(".");
if (e2) {
    Math.floor(e);
}

// if $e is less or equal to 0 - it is 0
if (e <= 0) {
    e = 0;
}

// $q = seconds
var q = (x - (f * a) - (d * b) - (h * c) - (m * e));

// Rewrite numbers if below 9
if (a <= 9) {
    xa = '0' + a;
} else {
    xa = a;
}
if (b <= 9) {
    xb = '0' + b;
} else {
    xb = b;
}
if (c <= 9) {
    xc = '0' + c;
} else {
    xc = c;
}
if (e <= 9) {
    xe = '0' + e;
} else {
    xe = e;
}
if (q <= 9) {
    xq = '0' + q;
} else {
    xq = q;
}

// Rewrite labels
if (a <= 1) {
    lb_ys = lb_y;
}
if (b <= 1) {
    lb_ds = lb_d;
}
if (c <= 1) {
    lb_hs = lb_h;
}
if (e <= 1) {
    lb_ms = lb_m;
}
if (q <= 1) {
    lb_ss = lb_s;
}

// if == 0 - do not show
if (a === 0) {
    a = '';
} else {
    a = a + ' ' + lb_ys;
}
if (b === 0) {
    b = '';
} else {
    b = b + ' ' + lb_ds;
}
if (c === 0) {
    c = '';
} else {
    c = c + ' ' + lb_hs;
}
if (e === 0) {
    e = '';
} else {
    e = e + ' ' + lb_ms;
}
if (q === 0) {
    q = '';
} else {
    q = q + ' ' + lb_ss;
}


var time = [a, b, c, e, q];

time = time.filter(Number);

var count = time.count();
var last = time[time.length - 1];

if (count == 1) {
    string = last;
} else if (count === 0) {
    string = '<i>No Time described</i>';
} else {
    string = time.join(', ') + ' ' + lb_and + ' ' + last;
}

return string;
}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = calTime(83200);
```

Comment: There are 86400 seconds in a day... And 31536000 in 365 days.

Comment: Use your console. `Uncaught TypeError: Object 0.005276509386098427 has no method 'indexOf`-> Line **52**.

Comment: Thanks.. didn't see that one.. not the solution for the problem.. but thanks..

Comment: Anyway, as a good practice when asking question on StackOverflow *or anywhere else*, **never** say "it doesn't work", but instead tell us what you expected it to do (sincerely, there's no "self explanatory" code when it's 100+ lines long) and what you got instead.

Comment: `The script speaks for itself.` No it doesn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll try to identify everything technically wrong with the script in one place.

1. **Incorrect time calculations**

   There's 86400 seconds in a day and 31536000 seconds in a 365-day year. You'll usually see people do things like this if they want to not worry about values:

   ```
   var minutes = 60;
   var hours = 60 * 60;
   var days = 24 * 60 * 60;
   var years = 365 * 24 * 60 * 60;
   ```
2. **Use of `indexOf()` on objects (in this case, numbers) that don't support that method.**

   Others have pointed this out in comments and answers, but basically, convert your numbers to strings if you're going to call string methods on them:

   ```
   num = num + "";
   numIndex = (num + "").indexOf("foo");
   ```
3. **Not properly checking the return value of `indexOf()`**

   `indexOf()` returns the index (from 0) of the location where the string starts.  If the string is not found, it returns -1. In several locations, you are doing something like:

   ```
   var a2 = a.indexOf("E-");
   if (a2) {
     a = 0;
   }
   ```

   a2, in this case, will be -1 if it does not match scientific notation. The only integer value considered `false` is 0. The -1 value is therefore always considered true and you're always setting your years, days and hours to 0, regardless of whether they are in a scientific notation format or not.
4. **Not considering case in the scientific notation format**

   In my browser, very small, close to zero values look like this:

   ```
   7.888609052210118e-31
   ```

   Your search won't match this value.  This may not even matter, given your logic. Is there any reason just not to always use `Math.floor()`? Your JS floating-point problem is going to be a problem any way you slice it.
5. **Not using the return value of Math.floor()**

   In several locations, you do something like the following:

   ```
   Math.floor(a);
   ```

   Then you go on to assume that `a` has assumed its floored value. You need to do the following to make that happen:

   ```
   a = Math.floor(a);
   ```
6. **Setting all of your time components to strings, and then filtering them by `Number`**

   You explicitly store string formats (e.g. 23 hours, 6 minutes) in your time array, but then, you filter the time array by `Number`. I think you're trying to filter out blank strings, which is what you set the time values to when they're 0. Pass a function to `filter()` to filter those blank entries out, like so:

   ```
   time.filter(function(x) { return x === "" ? false : true; });
   ```
7. **`count()` is not a method of `Array`**

   You're probably looking for `length`, which you actually use correctly below that.
8. **You join the entire time array together, then tack on the last item in the array again**

   I'll let you solve this. You don't want to duplicate the last item, and you probably also want to handle the case where the time evenly divides into one of your categories

Those are the technical things wrong with your script. Another complete answer could be written on more elegant ways in which to accomplish what you're trying to do.

Comment: Would I be able to simply skip the `a.indexOf("E-")` and go directly to the `a = Math.floor(a)` ? As you say.. This value `7.888609052210118e-31` is close to `0` But will the `Math.floor()` command detect this or simply cut `7.888609052210118e-31` down to `7`?

Comment: By the way - I love the way you are responding to the question.. i learned a lot more about javascript by reading your answer than the 10 hours I have been working on this script.. the Last thing you mentioned about the `join` of the array and that it would result in a duplicate of the last value. I was looking for a javascript way to say array_pop as in PHP. I just simply assumed that my `last` property would solve that for me.

Comment: @PhilipJensBramsted just try it in your console and see what it returns: `Math.floor(7.888609052210118e-31)`

Comment: @PhilipJensBramsted look at `Array.slice()` and try approaching it from the standpoint of two elements being joined by `' and '`, where the first element is a series of n elements (where n may be 0) joined by `', '`

Answer (score 1):

To add to the answers already given, the main style problem with your code is that there is a lot of unnecessary repetition, which you could get rid of using a loop and/or function.

Having said that, the maths can be greatly simplified, and there doesn't seem to be any need for all the stuff that searches for 'E' or '.', in which case it's probably not worth using a loop; in the suggestion below I use a loop only to add the labels. Another hint is to use descriptive variable names (`hours`, `minutes`, instead of `a`, `b`) where possible, to make your code more readable.

http://jsfiddle.net/m54Du/16/

```
function calTime(seconds) {
    if (seconds === '') {
        seconds = 54098;
    } // Time in seconds
    seconds = Math.floor(seconds);
    if (isNaN(seconds) || seconds <= 0) {
        return '<i>No time described</i>';
    }
    var minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60), 
        hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60),
        days = Math.floor(hours / 24), 
        years = Math.floor(days / 365), // assuming not leap!
        timeData = [years, days % 365, hours % 24, minutes % 60, seconds % 60],
        pluralLabels = ['years', 'days', 'hours', 'minutes' , 'seconds'],
        singularLabels = ['year', 'day', 'hour', 'minute', 'second'],
        time = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < timeData.length; i++) {
        if (timeData[i] > 1) {
            time.push(timeData[i] + ' ' + pluralLabels[i]);
        }
        else if (timeData[i] > 0) {
            time.push(timeData[i] + ' ' + singularLabels[i]);
        }
    }
    var last = time.pop();
    return time.length ? time.join(', ') + ' and ' + last : last;
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = calTime(83200);
```

[Here's an alternative](http://jsfiddle.net/m54Du/18/) making more use of a loop to do the maths.

Comment: What a beautiful script :O you just made my almost 200 lines of code down to 30 lines only..! That is so cool!

Comment: Your script only miss' one thing though - and that is the digital version ex `45:00` that was made with the `xa - xq` variables.

Answer (score 0):

Your variables a, b, etc. are numbers. indexOf is a method for strings in JavaScript.

One way of fixing this would be to turn your numbers into strings, like:

```
a = a + "";
```

which removes the indexOf() errors.

For the rest of the errors, I think you're also misusing functions. For example, you use a count() method, which doesn't appear to exist in JavaScript.